# Connecting to SQLExpress from a service

Tags: c#, windows-services, sql-server-express

We've got a service running as Local system. Should it be possible to use Integrated Security to connect to an SQLExpress instance from this service? It tries to login as "NT AUTHORITY/ANONYMOUS LOGON" and fails to connect.

Connection string is

```
Data Source=.\SQLExpress;Initial Catalog=Example;Integrated Security=true
```

What do I need to setup on SQLExpress to handle this?

Comment: Does your service really need Local System level access? I generally ensure that services are running in accounts with security shaped for that service. In other words, the service has access to stuff it is supposed to have access to and denied everything else. That way if the service is compromised the damage is limited. With Local System you've given it more access than an Administrator account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest running the service in an account dedicated for that service. THat way you can shape its security, thus limiting the damage if the service is compromised. It also means you know exactly what account to give to SQL Server and you can shape the security in there too.

Answer (score 2):

If you modify the service to run under a different local or AD account (Control Panel/Administration Tools/Services), then grant that same AD account access to the database, it should be able to access the database using Windows security.